# Parse error while comparing int values in a if statement

Tags: php, parsing, if-statement, casting, int

Currently I am working on a function that should change the pos values (int values) of an array like this one:

```
$comb = array(
    'A' => array('pos' => 3, 'lett' => 'C'),
    'B' => array('pos' => 4, 'lett' => 'D'),
    );
```

The function that should perform what i need is the following one:

```
function change($comb) {
    foreach ($comb as $value) {
        if($value['pos']== 1) {
            $value['pos'] = 4;
        } else {
            $value['pos']--;
        }
    }
}
```

I can not understand why during the execution of the code, an general parse error occurs at the line of the if condition. I tried casting $comb ['pos'] in int, but this does not seem to solve the problem.

Any idea?

Comment: Note that your adjustment of `$value['pos']` is meaningless because $value is not a reference to the entry in your `$comb` array, but a copy of the value that you're changing

Comment: Running the code, I find no parse error.

Comment: But exactly what error message are you getting?

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: I need that, by implementing once the function, the pos values of each element become respectively 3 and 4.

Comment: As regard the meaningless of the adjustment of $value['pos'], you are correct. I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to change $comb you should pass it as a reference (the & sign in parameters)

```
function change(&$comb) {
    foreach ($comb as $key => $value) {
        if($value['pos']== 1) {
            $comb[$key]['pos'] = 4;
        } else {
            $comb[$key]['pos']--;
        }
    }
}
```